# Windows search folders only one level

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

I have, in a Windows 10 machine, about 600 projects folder, and each of these folders have two folders: `current` and `old_releases`. All projects together have about 1TB.

To free space on the server, I want to delete all `old_releases` folder. So I thought I could quickly find them with the Windows Explorer search tool, since all folders are on the first level, and just hit *shift+delete* key. However, unfortunately, the searcher does not starts to look automatically through the first level, and takes a really long time to find all folders I want to remove.

I wonder if there is a way to limit the Windows explorer search for one level deep (I already [limited to look just for folders](https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-only-folders-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files) ). Is it possible?

If not, I would accept any suggestion to achieve my goal (delete those folders) easily...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
old_releases  kind:=folder -folderpath:x\*\
```

Note: Replace '`x`' with your main folder name.

Example...

```
old_releases  kind:=folder -folderpath:AllProjects\*\
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well it was not as fast as I expected (actually, I think it was pretty slow - it took some minutes to finish), but I've also made a quick test creating a few folders with that structure and some folders with the same name inside it, and it correctly found only the first level ones. So, I believe this is the best of what Windows can do...

Comment: It seems that this answer does not work for localized versions of Windows (I wonder why they deleted the English localization of options). @massic80 translated it for Italian users: ```old_releases tipologia:=cartella -percorsocartella:x\*\```